# Collision of two positrons: Is there any "strong force" that binds two positrons together to produce a positron-positron pair with $+2e$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, particle-physics, strong-force

I want to know if it is possible to hardly collide two positrons with each other to produce a pair with $+2e$. Indeed, I want to know if there is a *strong force*, similar to those binding protons together, which can hold particles of the same charge such as positrons together.

Answer (score 1):

No there isnt.Leptons(or anti-leptons)only interact with the photon field and the $W^{-},W^{+},Z$ fields

Answer (score 1):

If you collide them with enough energy they will form a black hole and the gravitational force will hold them together. You would end up with a black hole of charge $+2e$ and mass of about the Planck mass. However the collision would need a centre of mass energy of about $10^{19}~\textrm{GeV}$, which is $10^{15}$ times higher than the LHC can manage, so we will not be doing this experiment any time soon.

Well, we can't say this with any confidence as we have no theory that describes particle interactions at such high energies. So I should really say that while this is entertaining speculation it is no more than that. But gravity is your only hope. None of the other three fundamental forces would hold two positrons in a bound state.

Comment: This answer makes the assumption that GR is applicable to black holes created by quantum objects.

Answer (score 0):

Positrons, like electrons, are leptons so they do not feel the strong force. So in the same way as there is no bound state of two electrons, there is also no bound state of two positrons.

You can have a bound state of an electron and a positron, which is called  [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) (although it is unstable and quickly decays into gamma rays). You can also have an atom of [antihydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihydrogen) which consists of a positron and an antiproton - this is thought to be stable, as long as you can prevent it from interacting with "ordinary" matter. In theory, larger antimatter atoms can also exist, although they are much more difficult to create in practice.